# How to pass the dropdown list selected value from a php form to a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

The function of this web application is to: select a customer from the dropdown list (the dropdown list values are auto popup from the database), it will print the selected customer name and its postcode on the result page.

When I choose the customer name from the dropdown list and click the submit button, the result page only prints the $customerv value (the 1st echo), but the $result value (2nd echo) was not printed. The customer name is unique in the database.

index.php:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<form action="result.php" method="post">
Customer:<br>
    <select Customer id="customer" name="Customer">
      <option value="">--- Select Customer ---</option>
      <?php
      $sql = "SELECT b.BPName from BP b  where b.BPCode  like 'C%' Order by b.BPName";
      $customer = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      while ($cat = mysqli_fetch_array(
        $customer,
        MYSQLI_ASSOC
      )) :;

      ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $cat['BPName']; ?>">
          <?php echo $cat['BPName']; ?>
        </option>
      <?php
      endwhile;
      ?>
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</html>
```

config.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$databse = "xxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $databse);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

result.php:

```
<table>
<?php 
require_once('config.php');

    $customerv = $_POST['Customer'];
    echo $customerv;

    $sql = "SELECT shiptozipcode FROM BP WHERE BPName ='$customerv'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    echo $result;
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Why pass the name and not the primary identifier? You also are open to SQL injections, parameterize query and use prepared statements. You also should use OOP everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query result *itself* isn't something that's "printable" to the page.  It's not just a single value, it's a complex object.  You need to fetch the record(s) from the result.  For example:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo $row["shiptozipcode"];
}
```

If you're sure there will be only one row (it's still a good idea to add some error checking anyway) then you don't need the loop:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row["shiptozipcode"];
```

But either way, you need to extract the data from the result set.  (You could also use `fetch_object()` instead of `fetch_assoc()` if you prefer object syntax over array syntax.)

As an aside, be aware that your query is *wide open* to **SQL injection**.  Now would be a good time to [learn how to correct that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).